# Struggling to make an icon into a button

Tags: html, css, button

Im trying to make the icon im using into a button that when pressed, triggers the navigation bar to open. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="fixedBar">
    <h1>Company</h1>
    <a href="#" class="entypo-menu" id="showLeft"></a>
</div>
```

The class is the icon image and the id triggers the nav bar. The problem is that when I click the icon, the page scrolls back to the top due to the href of '#'.

Im not sure how I can get the icon to not link to anything when clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: That would mean that when I hover over the icon, the mouse cursor doesn't change to symbolise that it's clickable.

Comment: @George `cursor: pointer` in CSS

Comment: Thanks very much! I knew it wouldn't be hard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a href is not needed just use a fake link class

```
<span class="fake-link" id="fake-link-1"> fake link</span>

.fake-link {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `href`  attribute on your `a` , which is valid in HTML5. This will turn your link into a [placeholder hyperlink](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#placeholder-hyperlink).

If you're using Javascript in your application, you can set an event handler for the click, and use the `preventDefault()` method.

Code example with jQuery :

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```